# convert from PHP to JSON file to to draw chart wirth JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i want to extract data from the database and send as JSON file to the front-end and then try to draw graph. i have three tables notification where the website url is saved, status that has status and speed( google page speed) and a pivot table where all data related to a website is stored as values. i have model, and inside the model, i have a function that makes many to many relations between notifications and status table. 
i have a controller called chart controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChartController extends Controller
{

     public static function speedHistory(){

        $o_status = Status::where('name','speed')->first();
        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values AS value', 'created_at AS timestamp')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();


        if($o_response){
            return response()->json($o_response);
        }
            // return an empty json array instead of false
            //return false;
        return response()->json(array());
    }
}
```

and a front end page called app.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    $.getJSON("/json", function (result) {

        alert(result)
    }
```

and a route

```
Route::get('json','ChartController@speedHistory');
```

i use alert to see,if the data is going to app.js but it doesnt work. i would apperciate nay kind of help and suggestions?

this is the view file

```
extends('layout')

@section('header')
    <a class="logout" href="<?php echo 'login'?>">Logout</a>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}">               
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Crystal_button_cancel.svg/32px-Crystal_button_cancel.svg.png" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48">
    </a>
@stop

@section('content')
<script src="app.js"></script>
    <table class="table">
            <thead> 
            <h3>{{ $notification->website_url }}</h3>
                <tr> 
                    <th>date</th> 
                    <th>status</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
                <?php $notificationHealth = $notification->history('health'); ?>


                @foreach($notificationHealth as $status)

                    <tr>   
                        <td>{{ $status['timestamp'] }}</td>                         
                        <td> {{ $status['value'] }}</td>.
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <canvas id="pageSpeedHistoryChart" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
@stop

@section('footer')

@stop
```

Comment: Please clarify and add more details to your question, how do you invoke your controller's method, where is the view that loads your `app.js` and where in your view you invoke that method...

Comment: i am learning laravel, iam not even in view, i need to figure it out. but to invoke the controller i made a route as you can see in the code and from the app.js class i called the route $.getJSON("/json", function (result), then i used alert to check if it is invoking the controller

Comment: You need to know where your `app.js` is being called. Normally this is made in a view, with HTML code in it. Once you find out, you need to establish a connection to your controller by invoking its method (or the Route you defined) through the Javascript in that file or inside of that view.

Comment: oh thanks for the explanation! i need to read a bit about it. I am completely beginner for these things! i appreciate your advice.

Comment: i updated my code and added this view.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more details?

With /json you are calling a page under the same domain. Is this right?
You can use developer tools of chrome. Under network tab you can see the response of the call that you have done.